# Ошибка 10061 для сокетов клиента (С++) и сервера (Python)

Tags: сокет

написал тестовые клиент и сервер на питоне 3.6.2 64 бит tcp,sock_stream.
Работают.
Взял похожего клиента из другого приложения С++ с ws2_32.dll . Клиент успешно работает со своим аналогичным сервером.
Но! этот C++ клиент не выполняет connect  с сервером на питоне.
Ошибка 10061.
Выскажите какие - нибудь предложения пжста.

Comment: клиент не может установить соединение, потому что сервер "активно отказывается", например, просто делает close сокету.

Comment: Видимо плохо сформулировал:
Имеются:

Comment: Видимо плохо сформулировал:
Имеются:
1)Server на Python, Client on python - работают
2)Server C++, Client C++ - работают
3)Всё тот же Server Python, Client C++ - 10061 при попытке connect
Ведь казалось бы, что если connrct отослал приглашение, то далее это проблемы TCP, который одинаков с обоих концов
? почему.

Comment: может они на разные порты подключаются? И почему бы не попробовать ещё и четвертый вариант (сервер с++ и питон клиент)

Comment: Порт сервера, разумеется, указан один и тот же и в клиенте и в сервере. А сервер мне нужен именно на питоне.

Comment: очень сложно угадывать без кода, но у меня есть ещё подозрение, что загвоздка в том, что используются разные версии ip - v4/v6

Comment: Удалил преобразование htons из питона и всё заработало. Видимо в питоне это дtлает bind

Comment: Вот вот - оно подключалось на разные порты:) я был прав